# Prove that either all the elements of $G \setminus \{e \}$ are of infinite order or all the elements of $G$ are finite.

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Let $G$ be an abelian group. Suppose $H = \left \{g \in G\ \mid\ \text {either}\ \text {ord} (g)\ \text {is infinite or}\ g = e \right \}$ is a subgroup of $G.$ Then show that either all the elements of $G \setminus \{e \}$ are of infinite order or all the elements of $G$ are finite.

Let us suppose that not all the elements of $G$ are of finite order. Let $T$ denote the torsion subgroup of $G.$ Then by the given hypothesis we have $T \subsetneq G.$ We need to prove that order of all the elements of $G \setminus \{e\}$ are infinite. Suppose in contrary $\exists$ $a \in G \setminus \{e\}$ such that $\text {ord} (a) < + \infty.$ Then $T$ contains a non-trivial element $a.$ Now since $G \setminus T \neq \varnothing$ let $x \in G \setminus T.$ Then $ax \notin T$ for otherwise since $a \in T$ we have $x \in T,$ a contradiction. So $ax \in H.$ But this implies $a \in H,$ since $x \in H.$ But that means $a=e$ (since $\text {ord} (a) < +\infty$), a contradiction.

QED

Is it correct? Please verify it.

Comment: Where did I mention it @Peter?

Comment: Your proof looks correct to me.

Comment: Corrected it. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @Peter right. Thanks for the correction. Edited it accordingly. I am a Bengali. So English is not my mother tongue. Pardon me please.

Comment: No problem, I only want to understand the question.

Comment: @Peter are you from US? I have acquainted with a person also named "Peter" who was a TA of Prof. Benedict Gross. Are you the same person or some other? Please don't mind.

Comment: But I think you have to replace "all elements of $G$ are not of finite order" by "not all elements of $G$ are of finite order", in other words, there is an element with infinite order. In this case, the logic of the proof makes sense.

Comment: I am from Germany

Comment: Edited it @Peter. Again thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Oh! I see. You are a German!